# i want to change the background color after clicking?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change the background color after clicking

This is my HTML code

```
<td class="meun" onclick="getclick();">...</td>
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function getclick()
{
    this.style.background-color: #EFF2F7;
}
```

[`http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmCh/`](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZmCh/)

i want when click any on in the `td` in the table to change it's background color

Comment: A question is not formed just by ending a statement with a question mark.

Comment: Apart from some extra question marks (that I removed), it's a legit question (His english is not fluent, but that's not a requirement to post a question here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/3ZmCh/16/

You need to pass `this` as an argument and use proper JavaScript in the handler method:

```
function getclick(elem) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2F7';
}
```

Comment: thank u very much .. but what u advise me to learn this things .. how i can learn this stuff???

Comment: You might want to use jQuery - it's much easier to write nice code using it (e.g. by having no good reason to use inline event handlers).

Comment: i want when click an item in the table it's backgroundcolor change only and when click next item it's background color return to it's default and the other item change ....

Answer (score 1):

Your getclick() function should look like this:

```
function getclick(el)
{
    el.style.backgroundColor='#888888';
}
```

In js, styles look a little different

and in your td, do

```
<td onclick="getclick(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code in jQuery:

```
$("td").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color","#ABCDEF");
    });
```

Comment: not only is jQuery not what he asked for, your syntax is wrong.  (I didn't down-vote you btw)

Comment: @Groovetrain - From the jQuery docs, the start of the 2nd paragraph on the ".css(propertyName, value)" section: "Also, jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of multiple-word properties." (link: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

Comment: well frik!  Back in the 1.3.2 days, it wouldn't've worked.  Guess I'm behind the times. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function changeBGC(color){
document.bgColor = color;
}
//-->
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="javascript:changeBGC('#000099')">Click Blue</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the id to your `<td>` tag and change the name of function for a better understanding.

```
function changeBgColor() {

var tableData = document.getElementById('meun');

tableData.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2F7';

}




<td id='meun' class="meun" onclick="changeBgColor()">...</td>
```