# how can i change the background of an item in the table?

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [i want to change the background color after clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678532/i-want-to-change-the-background-color-after-clicking)

how can i change the background of an item in the table ?

and when the mouse is over any item it's color changed so i used that `CSS` code:

```
.meun:hover{
         background-color: #EFF2F7;
}
```

that's fine so to change the background color of the clicked item i used this little java-script code

```
function getclick(elem)
{
    elem.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2F7';
}
```

So i want now if i clicked other item the previous item return it's default color which is `white` and the next item change and the `hover` in css keep working that's like the `facebook` left menu...

for more details this is the code i had written

http://jsfiddle.net/NA8Dj/

Comment: Are you willing to use a JavaScript library such as jQuery? Although, this will only be a few lines of raw JavaScript.

Comment: @Free, this is not a dup.  In the first question, he was using CSS syntax (`.background-color`) for a javascript property.  In this question, he has learned from that, and is now trying to introduce hovering.

Comment: Why was this flagged as offensive?

Comment: This is not a dup.  One is talking about changing the background colour of a cell, the other is talking about changing the background colour of an item within that cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css class with your custom style (instead of explicitly setting background color) to those elements and then modify your function like:

```
function getclick(elem)
{
//find any elemenet with given class
//remove that class from it
//add that class to 'elem'
}
```

I don't know correct syntax in pure javascript, but with jQuery, it could be:

```
// find any element with given class and remove it
$('.yourClass').removeClass('yourClass');
// add that class to clicked element
elem.addClass('yourClass');
```

You can see [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/XMbAS/7/).
Btw: Your example didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with pure JavaScript. It uses *event delegation*, which means that only **one** click handler is assigned to the table, and not to each cell:

```
(function() {
    var current,
        table = document.getElementById('table'); // I gave the table 
                                                  // the uncreative ID `table`
    table.onclick = function(event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

        if(target.nodeName !== 'TD') {
            do {
               target = target.parentNode;
            } while(target && target.nodeName !== 'TD');
        }

        if(target) {
            if(current) {
                current.style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
            target.style.backgroundColor = '#EFF2F7';
            current = target;
        }
    };
}());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/NA8Dj/7/)